# GT-I9082 - Unable to enter download mode through ADB

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, samsung-galaxy-grand

I have a really old Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos from 5 years back.

I want to boot into download mode using ADB. I am using the following command

```
adb -s <deviceid> reboot download
```

What this does is just reboot my phone and does not take me to recovery. I can boot into recovery though using

```
adb reboot recovery
```

I have tried the commands

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

also has no effect other than booting my phone.

I can enter into recovery the manual way using `volume down + power + home` button, but why can't I enter it using ADB ?

What am I doing wrong ?

My phone is running Jellybean Samsung Stock ROM and does not have the fastboot/bootloader mode.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I have Grand Duos too and I can confirm it is **perfectly** bootable into Odin Mode (aka Download) by

```
adb reboot download
```

Tried it just now.

What I can propose to you:

1. Try to get rid of all other emulated/physical devices by restarting ADB-server and/or ejecting non-necessary ones.

   ```
   adb kill-server
   ```

I can guess you have them as you use `-s` clause.

2. Learn the difference [between Odin Mode, recovery mode and bootloader mode](http://zidroid.com/boot-android-devices-to-download-fastboot-recovery-mode-using-adb/). Maybe you are confusing them?

I have custom recovery but this doesn't prevent me from booting into all this modes.

Comment: Does not work just reboots device